# Android RecyclerView infinity scrolling: how to add more items to dataset

Tags: android, infinite-scroll, android-recyclerview

I have implemented my RecyclerView and even added an onscrolllistener to support infinity scrolling and now I'm stuck with a, hopefully, easy problem: **How can I add the newly loaded data to the existing dataset?**

My current approach: I create a new array with the length of the existing dataset + the length of the newly loaded data. I `System.arraycopy` my existing dataset and add the new content with a for-loop.

This works but the list is always reset (scrolls back to the top) and I assume my way to add additional content is overly complicated/wrong, though the tutorials I have looked at seem to pass over this "detail".

Update: I'm currently calling "scrollToPosition" on the UI-Thead after the data has been loaded, but I doubt this is the correct way of doing this or am I wrong?

Comment: So, what you are saying. You want an infinite scrolling RecyclerView ?

Comment: Exactly, the same as with listview, just with a recyclerview (it already works, though I'm not sure if I add the new data correctly to my existing data.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be adding stuff to your dataset, you will sooner or later run out of memory. What you can do is return a big number (I used `Short.MAX_VALUE`) item in `getItemCount` inside your adapter and in the method that requests a view for postion you should do `position % list.size();`

It is not a truly endless `RecyclerView` this way, but good enough. I will paste some code tomorrow, I don't have it here now :/

Comment: But isn't the RecyclerView used so you don't run out of memory, not matter the list size?

Comment: RecyclerView is only recycling view items, not your dataset. You will run out of memory because of your dataset

Comment: The dataset is quite simple and per item only consists of a couple of strings. When the user starts the app, only 8 items are being loaded, after reaching the bottom, an additional 8 items are loaded and so on. Considering this use case, how would you create a list with "infinite" scrolling?

Comment: A lot of Strings can take up a lot of memory you know. Especially if they are lengthy. Do items need to change, or can they be the same? What is changing? I made an "endless" adapter by returning a lot of items and then scrolling to the middle, so the end effect is that is repeating items endlessly

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add items inside your adapter. Let`s say

```
class Adapter extends Recycler.Adapter<Recycler.ViewHolder>{
      List<YourCustomObject> list;
      public Adapter(){
          list = new ArrayList<>();
      }


      public void addItem(YourCustomObject item){
          list.add(item);
          notifyItemDateSetChanged(); //This method for adapter to notice that list size have been changed
      }

      // Here your views

}
```

There is implementation of Your fragment or Activity where you retrieve data from internet.Let` say

```
class MainActivity extends AppCompactActivity{
     Adapter adapter = new Adapter();
     List<YourCustomObjects> objects;
     public void onCreateView(){
     //////// Something yours
     }

     public void onLoadMore(){

     /////  Your operation to retrieve data and init it to your list objects
     for(YourCustomObject object : objects){
         adapter.addItem(object);
     } 

     }
}
```